SATA SSD not detect in BIOS, stuck on loading in computer management, but shows up in Acronis
Brand 1TB: FIKWOT Solid State Drive - This one: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0B4J9HHW6
I have this SSD SATA drive below. I plugged it into my computer and the bios doesn't detect it. But when I plug it in via a USB adapter it just stuck on loading, but detects the drive in Acronis, see below.
It was working fine for a good 6 months running windows 10. Now it just doesn't detect. I'd like to access my data back if possible.
What could be the issue with this SSD that its not detecting properly?



This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

updated. what more details do you like?

Either the controller or flash has died. If you absolutely must get the data back then you may well have to contact a data recovery service.

@Patoshiパトシ - I don't trust your motherboard has a m.2 SATA capability.  I also don't trust it's a SATA.  I don't have the required information to do any research. Specifications on Amazon are not reliable.

@Ramhound It's a traditional SATA drive, just a different form factor with only the chips in the PCB without the 2.5" enclosure. It's not M.2. Any board supports SATA drives with data+power cable.

@ChanganAuto - What is displayed in the screenshot isn't a 2.5" SATA connector. This is why I wanted more information.  The Amazon specifications just indicate SATA.

@Ramhound It's the exact same thing. The photos show the internals without the enclosure. The exploded view in the 4th image at Amazon shows the same. I have many of this.
